# How to stop android print framework dialog dismissing after screen rotation?

Tags: android, printing, dialog

I write a Printer class in Android app, everything works well until I rotate the screen, the print option dialog on the top of screen in portrait mode will dismiss, I want to maintain the print framework dialog, I try to set `android:configChange` but it does not help. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I find this comment in PrintManager code,

```
Calling this method will bring the print dialog and
 * the system will connect to the provided {@link PrintDocumentAdapter}. If a
 * configuration change occurs that you application does not handle, for example
 * a rotation change, the system will drop the connection to the adapter as the
 * activity has to be recreated and the old adapter may be invalid in this context,
 * hence a new adapter instance is required. As a consequence, if your activity
 * does not handle configuration changes (default behavior), you have to save the
 * state that you were printing and call this method again when your activity
 * is recreated.
```